# SQL Server syntax: search_condition and [ ,...n ]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it correct to use [[ ,...n ]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql) in context of [search conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql).

```
<search_condition> ::=   
    { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) }   
    [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } ]   
[ ,...n ]
```

This element is used to indicate that some part of the syntax can be repeated. In this case, through commas. But I cannot imagine this in practice.

Comment: . . No, commas are not appropriate.

Comment: The grammar should have used `[...n]`